# Keycloak init function returns Uncaught (in promise) undefined

Tags: reactjs, keycloak, keycloak-services

**This is my keycloak code in react for authentication it redirects to the login page and when the user is already authenticated it works good as well too But didn't execute the inner of the function Doesn't set the loggedin to true and doesn't consoles the keycloak value
and in console this exception appears "Uncaught (in promise) undefined I have tried making it async and try to catch the promise but it returns Promise rejection "**

```
React.useEffect(() => {
      const keycloak = Keycloak("./keycloak.json");
keycloak.init({onLoad: 'login-required'}).then(async function(authenticated) {
SetLoggedin(true)
console.log(keycloak)


  })
```